# What causes part of text to exceed the background color?

Tags: css, background, background-color

I was playing around with the background color of text when I noticed that certain characters like **Á** exceed the background color why is that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rawhkd5/)

html

```
<div class='test'>
    abcdefÁĀ
</div>
```

css

```
.test{
background: green;
font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox.

Comment: No character exceeding the background color in your jsfiddle, check it again, I checked it with Chrome .

Comment: Happens in Firefox, but not in Chrome/Safari/Opera for me, OS X 10.10.

Comment: @amr I checked it again and like said it only happens in firefox chrome/safari/opera are fine

Comment: @Siguza Yeah you are right only happens in firefox.

Comment: @nablore I test it again with Firefox 39, and it's work fine too, I think it's all about encode either ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 facing problem with this character, If you define the encode as utf-8, It will be fine everywhere.